# What kind of neural network should I use for getting probabilities?

Tags: neural-network

I have input data as Х={characteristic1, characteristic2,..} and I want to get Y = probability(12% or 45% and etc). I would like to use RBF(radial basis function) neural network for this. Is it a good choice? I'm new at this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: I don't get it if your target variable is nominal, ordinal or binary you get probabilities in every model.